# Copying all chars from AWT font to an OpenGL texture array

Tags: java, opengl, fonts, lwjgl

I'm trying to copy all the chars from an AWT font into a OpenGL array for LWJGL to use. Currently my code isn't working (blank textures). What I tried was to draw each char into a `BufferedImage` along with a transparent background, then copy it pixel-by-pixel onto a `ByteBuffer` for an OpenGL image. My question is, what is a better way around copying these chars? `BufferedImage` doesn't seem to be working. Is there another canvas type I can use for this?

So far this is the layout, but it doesn't work, I need a new way to draw onto the textures:

```
for (int i = 0; i <= 255; i++)
    {
        String letter = Character.toString((char)i);

        BufferedImage image = new BufferedImage(size, size, BufferedImage.TYPE_INT_ARGB);
        Graphics2D g = image.createGraphics();
        g.setColor(new Color(255, 255, 255, 0));
        g.drawRect(0, 0, size, size);
        g.setColor(new Color(255, 255, 255));
        g.setFont(font);
        g.drawString(letter, 0, 0);

        int id = i;

        glTextures[id] = glGenTextures();
        glBindTexture(GL_TEXTURE_2D, glTextures[id]);

        glTexParameteri(GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_MIN_FILTER, GL_LINEAR);
        glTexParameteri(GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_MAG_FILTER, GL_LINEAR);

        ByteBuffer buf = ByteBuffer.allocateDirect(4 * 4 * size * size);
        for (int x = 1; x <= size; x++)
        {
            for (int y = 1; y <= size; y++)
            {
                Color color = new Color(image.getRGB(x - 1, y - 1));
                buf.putFloat((float)(1 / 255 * color.getRed()));
                buf.putFloat((float)(1 / 255 * color.getGreen()));
                buf.putFloat((float)(1 / 255 * color.getBlue()));
                buf.putFloat((float)(1 / 255 * color.getAlpha()));
            }
        }
        buf.flip();

        glTexImage2D(GL_TEXTURE_2D, 0, GL_RGBA, 2, 2, 0, GL_RGBA, GL_FLOAT, buf);
    }
```

Comment: That's a lot of textures, are you sure that you don't just want a single texture containing all the characters?

Comment: I can, but at the moment I'm trying to keep it simple. I don't see how my current setup would hurt as long as keep the amount of `GLFont` instances to a minimum.

Comment: The pain is that you'd need a draw call for every character and you'd be continuously binding textures. It will work, but will be relatively slow. It's much more straight forward to start with a grid (don't even have to make a packed atlas) of glyphs and create a VBO for each string (the VBO contains the texture coordinates for each character).

Comment: Could I use a Display List instead? Would that give me a performance increase? I personally don't like the new OpenGL methods.

Comment: You shouldn't use DisplayLists because they are deprecated.